# HTML GeoLocation Push notification

Tags: javascript, html, push-notification, geolocation

Is there a way to detect a specific location (which is stored in the client) automatically from a website and send a push notification on this website?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Comment: I think my question was not detailed enough. i know the geo location api. What i want is that the website check by itself if the user come to an specific location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Geolocation API write code that'll, at an interval, validate if the user's location coordinates are "close" to the coordinates of the specific location